# Копия указателя, которая имеет область видимости меньше, чем оригинал. С++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
  int *val1 = new int(1);
  {
      int *val = val1;
  }
  std::cout << *val1;
}
```

Если `val` указывает на тот же адрес, что и `val1` , будет ли при выходе из блока(где создается `val`) память, на которую указывал `val1` считаться свободной?  Если да, то как можно сделать так,чтобы создать копию указателя внутри блока и при выходе из которого не будет становиться свободной

Answer (score 5):

В языке С++ динамическая память никогда автоматически не освобождается. Пока вы сами явно не вызовете `delete` память освобождена не будет. Динамическая память для того в первую очередь и предназначена, чтобы создавать объекты, время жизни которых не зависит от границ блоков. С точки зрения ядра языка, управление динамической памятью в С и С++ делается только явно вручную: выделение вручную и освобождение вручную.

Язык С++ предоставляет библиотечные решения для автоматизации менеджмента динамической памяти - стандартные классы "умных указателей". Но только вы сами можете воспользоваться этими классами. В вашем примере вы пользуетесь голыми сырыми указателями, которые никогда ничего за вас освобождать не будут.

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое